# SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined google maps

Tags: c#, jquery, google-maps

I am using google maps. And I can see the google map. But I get every this error:

SCRIPT5009: 'google' is undefined

My script is this:

```
var map;

if (typeof initMap == 'function') {
    initMap();
}

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: 52.001321, lng: 4.374577 }

    });


    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
}//end function initMap

$("document").ready(function () {

     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
});


//function loadScript() {
//    var script = document.createElement('script');
//    script.type = 'text/javascript';
//    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initMap';
//    document.body.appendChild(script);
//}

//addLoadEvent(loadScript);




function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

var marker;
var infowindow;
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
        infowindow.close();
    }

    if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "Drag me!"
            });

            //document.getElementById(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)).className += "geolocation_long";
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'            


        });      

        document.getElementById("form_inp17").value = marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6);
        document.getElementById("form_inp18").value = marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.close();
            }
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'
            });

            document.getElementById("form_inp17").value = event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
            document.getElementById("form_inp18").value = event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)

            infowindow.open(map, marker);


        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);




        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And my html page where I refer to the google maps is like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Form/Views/Shared/_RenderLayout.cshtml";
} 


@section SFSHeadSection {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/xforms")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/xforms_" + ViewBag.Locale)

    @if (ViewBag.Includes != null){
        @Scripts.Render(ViewBag.Includes);
    }
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.onloadscript)
        });
    </script>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery-ui.css") 
    @Styles.Render("~/css/Geo-picker.css")



    <style type="text/css">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.style)
    </style>
}

<div>
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.FormHtml)
</div>
```

Thank you

and yes, I already looked at this thread:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940872/script5009-google-is-undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: ?? What do you mean? If you load the map